# View center according to its ViewcController - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, frame

I have a `UIView` inside another `UIView`.

What is the best way to set the inner `UIView` position according to the `ViewController` `View`, and not to its `superView`?

```
func answerViewTapAction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let myViewIndex = returnActiveView() {
        var choosenView: numberView!
        print("view \(myViewIndex) will move to slot \(sender.view!.tag)")
        for noView in noViews {
            if noView.tag == myViewIndex {
                choosenView = noView
            }
        }
        //print(choosenView.center)
        print(sender.view!.center)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, animations: {
            choosenView.center = CGPoint(
                x: CGRectGetMidX(sender.view!.frame),
                y: CGRectGetMidY(sender.view!.frame))
        })
    }else {
        print("view will not move")
    }   
}
```

I want to access my `sender.view` center according to the `ViewController`, not according to its `superView`.

Comment: add a name to the childView and access or set properties to it

Comment: about the code I'm just trying to access its center and found out it gets it coordinates according to its superview

Comment: @jdave could you please explain this in an answer, i didn't quit get you.

Comment: Post your code please so we know exactly what we're dealing with.

Comment: @ZGski posted the code. Thanks

Comment: to GET its position not to SET. :p typo

Comment: "What is the best way to get the inner UIView position according to the ViewController" Makes no sense. A View Controller is not a view and has no notion of position or coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `convertPoint` method of `UIView`. In particular the `convertPoint(_ point: CGPoint, toView view: UIView?) -> CGPoint`. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:toView:).

If you need an example let me know. You just need to call it once and pass the `toView` your superview of the view you're trying to figure out.

EDIT: to the example we go!

Let's consider three views: A, B and C. And a fancy ASCII art to go along.

```
(0, 0, 20, 20)
+----------------------------------+
| A                                |
|    (5, 5, 10, 10)                |
|    +--------------------+        |
|    |B                   |        |
|    |    (5, 5, 5, 5)    |        |
|    |    +-----------+   |        |
|    |    |C          |   |        |
|    |    |           |   |        |
|    |    |           |   |        |
|    |    |           |   |        |
|    |    |           |   |        |
|    |    |           |   |        |
|    |    |           |   |        |
|    |    +-----------+   |        |
|    |                    |        |
|    |                    |        |
|    +--------------------+        |
|                                  |
|                                  |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

View A is the `ViewController.view` and it's at X: 0, Y: 0, width: 20, and height: 20.
View B is a subview of A and it's at X: 5, Y: 5, width: 10, height: 10 according to view A.
View C is a subview of B and it's at X: 5, Y: 5, width: 5, height: 5 according to view B.
But according to view A the C is actually at X: 10, Y: 10 because the view B is at 5, 5.
So what we need to to to figure out the origin of view C according to view A is to `convertPoint`.

The way to do it:

```
let originOfC = B.convertPoint(C.frame.origin, toView: A)
```

And that's it. You can do the same thing programatically with a fiew loops but the example above is somewhat cleaner. Now I have given you an example for the origin. To get the center you can use the `view.center` property or add a half of the C width to x coordinate of `originOfC` and half of the height to y of `originOfC`.

Comment: Updated with the example.